# Sum up dynamic fields in list

Tags: list, coldfusion, lucee

I have a list like:

```
<cfset list ="group 1:1; group 2:4; group a:7; group 1:3; group a:1;">
```

What I want to do is count (sum up) how many people are in group 1, group 2, group a, etc.. Now these fields are dynamic, so I don't know the exact name of the groups.

So the end result in this example is:

```
group 1: 4
group 2: 4
group a: 8
```

So the list is just an example, in reality it's much bigger with more groups (dynamic names). I'm using Coldfusion/Lucee. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one of numerous of possible alternative ways of doing this. Starting from using a query instead of a list as the starting value.

What I am doing is to loop the list with `;` as delimiter and adding the values to a structure. I later use that structure to loop and list the final total.

```
<cfset list ="group 1:1; group 2:4; group a:7; group 1:3; group a:1;">
<cfset totalStruct = {}>
<cfloop list="#list#" item="group" delimiters=';'>
  <cfset groupName = listFirst(group, ':')>
  <cfset groupNameKey = replace(groupName, ' ', '', 'all')>
  <cfset groupValue = val(listLast(group, ':'))>
  <cfif !structKeyExists(totalStruct, groupNameKey)>
    <cfset totalStruct[groupNameKey] = {name:groupName, total=groupValue}>
  <cfelse>
    <cfset totalStruct[groupNameKey].total += groupValue>
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>
  <ul>
    <cfloop collection="#totalStruct#" item="group">
      <li>#totalStruct[group].name# : #totalStruct[group].total#</li>
    </cfloop>
  </ul>
</cfoutput>
```

**[DEMO](https://trycf.com/gist/650fe80fc7fbbc05a98f639d81962459/lucee5?theme=monokai)**

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use the `map` and/or `reduce` closure functions to parse your list.

*NOTE 1: I generally find cfscript to be much easier for most things for parsing text or "looping".*

*NOTE 2: I'm not a huge fan of loops, especially around large text values. Closure functions will likely be much more performant.*

```
<cfset lst ="group 1:1; group 2:4; group a:7; group 1:3; group a:1;">
```

First, with a `map()` inside of a function:

```
<cfscript>
    public Struct function parseLst (required String lst) {
        var retval = {} ; //// Default return variable. 
        //// https://docs.lucee.org/reference/functions/listmap.html
        arguments.lst.listmap(    
            function(el) {
                var k = el.listFirst(":").ltrim() ; /// Get the "key" and strip extra leading space.
                var v = el.listLast(":") ; /// Get the "value".
                
                var p = retval["#k#"]?:0 ; /// Use Elvis to default to 0 if no struct Key exists. 
                
                retval["#k#"] = v + p ; /// Set the value of the key. NOTE: A struck key with the same name will generally overwrite itself. We want to add it.
            }
            ,";" /// Specify the delimiter of the list. 
        ) ;
        
        return retval ;
    }

    writeDump(parseLst(lst));
</cfscript>
```

Then with a `reduce()` without being inside a function.

```
<cfscript>
    //// https://docs.lucee.org/reference/functions/listreduce.html
    r = listReduce(lst,
        function(prev,nxt){
            k = nxt.listFirst(":").ltrim() ;  /// Get the "key" and strip extra leading space.
            /// To shorten it, I just skipped setting the value beforehand and just did it while setting the struct value. Same method as above.
            prev["#k#"] = (nxt.listLast(":"))+(prev["#k#"]?:0) ; 
            return prev ;
        }
        ,
        {}    // Initial value
        ,";"  // Delimiter
    ) ;
    

    writedump(r) ;
</cfscript>
```

Both could (and probably should) be inside a function, and then you could just send your list variable to it.

And if possible, it might be a lot easier to fix the original list to be simpler to work with.

https://trycf.com/gist/dda51d88504a625fce5548142d73edb3/lucee5?theme=monokai

=======================================================

**EDIT:**

An alternative to using `listFirst/Last()` functions would be to just convert the "list" to an array and then use those pieces to get your "key" and "value".

```
<cfscript>
    //// https://docs.lucee.org/reference/functions/listreduce.html
    s = listReduce(lst,
        function(prev,nxt){
            var elem = nxt.listToArray(":") ;
            
            prev["#elem[1].ltrim()#"] = elem[2] + (prev["#elem[1].ltrim()#"]?:0) ;
            return prev ;
        }
        ,
        {}    // Initial value
        ,";"  // Delimiter
    ) ;
    

    writedump(s) ;
</cfscript>
```